# Sound not played when collecting Coin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-source

I am new to game development and building Endless Runner game, where Rocky(Player) can collect coins, and I applied cool sound effect when coin is being collected by player but that is not played. Here is the detail what I did so far,

**First I create an Empty Object named it CollectCoin and drop coin collect sound on it.**

[image: CoinCollect game object]

**Inspector View of CoinCollect, as can see CoinSFX is applied on AudioClip property**

[image]

**Coin Object look like this at inspector view and my AudioSource applied there in scripts. Also check Is Trigger checkbox**

[image]

**Player Inspector View**

[image]

And finally my Class

```
public class CoinCollect : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AudioSource coinFX;
    public void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        coinFX.Play();
        
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        
    }
}
```

What and where i done wrong so far? I am stuck here since yesterday. Please help me.

Comment: Does your camera have an AudioListener?

Comment: Yes, I Just checked it does have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with my script, and I dragged both Coin Collect Sound and Background Music at correct place, problem was with my Unity, I don't know when I muted "Mute Audio" option in unity, or its muted by default i have no idea but my problem is resolved. That is why my sound was not playing

[image]